# incorrect vertical navigation items alignment

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to customize Navigation bar and get it bigger with vertical alignment. Here is my code:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var topNavTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var topNavStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftNavHomeButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightNavSearchButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var rightNavSearchButton_: UIBarButtonItem?

    @IBAction func searchAction(sender: UIButton) {

        topNavStackView.hidden = true
        topNavStackView.hidden = false
        rightNavSearchButton_ = rightNavSearchButton
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }

    @IBAction func performSearch(sender: UIButton) {
        topNavStackView.hidden = false
        topNavStackView.hidden = true
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  rightNavSearchButton_
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let navConBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            navConBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width, 100)
            navConBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10.0, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            let offset = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(offset, forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitlePositionAdjustment(offset, forBarMetrics: .Default)
        }
    }
```

When It appears it looks ok.

[image: alignment is ok]

But When I click on right navigation bar button, left button goes to down.

[image: alignment isn't ok]

Also when it turns back:

[image: alignment isn't ok]

How can it be fixed?

Comment: What is the purpose of hiding and showing topNavStackView in a row?

Comment: Please, try to explain in your question, what is the goal you want to achieve. This way it may not work either. I see you try to put UITextfield inside the UINavigationItem. I wouldn't do anything like that.

Comment: there are two views actually: one is just label, when you click on right button it disappears and stack view appears, which contains button and text field

Comment: UITextfield is search field

Comment: OK, so sorry I can't help you. I would definitely use UISearchBar. Users are used to tap under navbar to make search. And iOS comfortably cares about these kind of needs, e.g. keyboard (dis)appearing.

Comment: I'm try to achieve when you click on right button (show search field), text field appears, after clicking on search button, it disappears and label appears agian